# why is my caeser cipher only printing the last letter of string? python

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def caesar_cipher(offset, string):
    words = string.replace(" ", " ")
    cipher_chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    word_i = 0
    while word_i < len(words): 
        word = words[word_i]

        letter_i = 0 
        while letter_i < len(word): 
            char_i = ord(word[letter_i]) - ord("c")
            new_char_i = (char_i + offset) % 26
            value = chr(new_char_i + ord("c"))
            letter_i += 1
        word_i += 1

    return words.join(value)
print caesar_cipher(3, "abc")
```

Hey everyone, for some reason my ceasar cipher is only printing the last letter in my string, when I want it to cipher the whole string, for example, if i print an offset of 3 with string "abc" it should print def, but instead is just printing the f.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the matter with spaces with spaces in line 2? Is that supposed to be `words = string.split(" ")`?

Comment: And why are you subtracting and adding `ord('c')`? This way `value`can only contain characters `c`to `z`, `{`and `|`. (Since `0 <= new_char_i <= 25`.)

Comment: @RobinKoch i originally had it as string.split, but changed it to replace to see what that would do. Still new to development and algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` is overwritten in the loop. You want to create a list passed to `join` (ATM you're joining only 1 character):

```
value = []
```

then

```
value.append(chr(new_char_i + ord("c")))
```

the `join` statement is also wrong: just do:

```
return "".join(value)
```

Note that there are other issues in your code. It seems to intent to process several words, but it doesn't, so a lot of loops don't loop (there's no list of words, it's just a word), so what you are doing could be summarized to (using a simple list comprehension):

```
def caesar_cipher(offset, string):
    return "".join([chr((ord(letter) - ord("c") + offset) % 26 + ord("c")) for letter in string])
```

and for a sentence:

```
print(" ".join([caesar_cipher(3, w) for w in "a full sentence".split()]))
```

As a nice commenter noted, using `c` as start letter is not correct since it trashes sentences containing the 3 last letters. There's no reason not to start by `a` (the result are the same for the rest of the letters):

```
def caesar_cipher(offset, string):
    return "".join([chr((ord(letter) - ord("a") + offset) % 26 + ord("a")) for letter in string])
```

Aside: a quick similar algorithm is `rot13`. Not really a cipher but it's natively supported:

```
import codecs
print(codecs.encode("a full sentence","rot13"))
```

(apply on the encoded string to decode it)

Comment: does seem to work, but is now printing dabceabcf which has the answers in it, but I am trying to get it to just print def if the string givin is abc

Comment: still just getting the last letter returned when defined in the first loop, but when I print value it print the bracket 3 times

Comment: oh I see what you did there. thank you I'm still new to writing code.

Comment: I really like how you simplified the code to one line. I need more practice to learn how to do that.

Comment: Your code handles the output of `a` and `b`wrong.
Since it uses `c` as "origin", it outputs `{`and `|` instead. Try: `print(caesar_cipher(0, "abcxyz"))`. Use `ord("a")` instead.

Comment: @RobinKoch you're probably right. I was just copying the OP's algorithm. `c` is probably not the logical start. But It still works for me. `a` issues `d` whatever the origin. That's probably because of the `offset` parameter that fixes it. But I'm not sure of the usefulness of both `c` and offset = 3... Should be no offset and `a` as origin.

Comment: @Johnny just some practice. When a subset of the input data is in output, you probably can use list comprehensions and one-liners.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, but as I mentioned `caesar_cipher(3, "xyz")` returns `}|c` instead `abc`.

Comment: @RobinKoch I originally had it as "a" was just messing around with different letters to see if it worked the same